# How I Can Check xmlhttp.readyState with setTimeout every 10 milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hi I am new in java script ,How I can use instead of `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()`
check the state of function, `xmlhttp.readyState` ,every 10 milliseconds, with `setTimeout` ,i don't know how to do it every 10 milliseconds.

thank you.

Comment: I would be more interested in knowing WHY would you want to do it?

Comment: Becouse on some computers my application doesn't work ,it doesn't save the changes and I red that it might be a problem,xmlhttp.onreadystatechange.

Answer (score 1):

`xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` will be *called* whenever it changes state.

You don't need a `setTimeout` to check the value of `xmlhttp.readyState`.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log("readyState is now: " + xmlhttp.readyState);
}
```

You *could* do something like:

```
var state = 0;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    state = xmlhttp.readyState;
}
setInterval(function () {
    console.log("readyState is now: " + state );
}, 100); // prints the readystate every 100ms
```

But I don't see why you'd need to do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

This will function will continually recurse every 10ms:

```
(function readyStateCheck(){

        //code to do the ready-state check

        if  (!someBreakingCondition){

            setTimeout(readyStateCheck, 10);

        }

})()
```

Comment: Don't forget some `if` logic to finally end this loop, too!

Comment: Frits answer (+1) probably makes this OBE. But one note: there are subtle differences between calling `setTimeout`, and `setInterval`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/731625/613004

Comment: Hi I found what the problem I think my javascript doesn't work with IE9+,so I Don't know How to fix the xmlhttp.